# Accessing camera in android webview

Tags: android, html, asp.net, camera

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've researched but haven't founda anything that actually helps because it's either outdated or doesn't work.

I've written a web app with asp.net which is then linked to in android/iOS-apps, in the app I want to access camera or storage to upload an image, so far so good! In iOS it works pretty much without issues, and if I open it in a browser on android it works as well, but the application opens it through webview and at this point all hell breaks loose. I don't get prompted to select camera/storage but instead I get to select file from storage instantly, but not only from photos but all files I've got stored on the phone.
The code snippet that is used to access camera looks like this:

```
    <input type="file"
        asp-for="Picture"
        accept="image/*"
        capture="capture" />
```

All permissions that should be needed is there and I'm quite lost as to what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to below Code

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: That's basically what I started out with, but it didn't work. As I stated above, it works with various browsers in android but not in webview. It works well in iOS and desktop browsers, any other ideas?

Comment: I don't have access to the app, nor do I think it's written like this. It's built with a tool that basically links interactive websites to buttons and then opens them in webview. Which means I can't use that class. The solution needs to be through html or JS, which makes it seem rather difficult to find a working solution. If you've got any other suggestions I'm open for trying though!